# Values from ms sql gives error when subtracted in php

Tags: php, sql-server

I Tried subtracting two values been fetched from ms sql server but I was getting error.

Below is my query:

```
$amtdue = "select sum(case  when principal < 0 then principal else 0 end) as overdue, sum(case  when principal >= 0
                            then principal else 0 end) as overdue2  from loanhist where ac_no='$id' and trx_date <='$date' group by ac_no";
                            $amt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $amtdue);
                            $aod = sqlsrv_fetch_array($amt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

                            $amtdues = "select loan_amt from loans where ac_no='$id'";
                            $amts = sqlsrv_query($conn, $amtdues);
                            $lo = sqlsrv_fetch_array($amts, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Here are the values:

```
                              $m = $lo['loan_amt']; //$m = 100000
                              $p = $aod['overdue']; //$p = -169172
                             $su = substr($p,1);
                             echo $su - $p;
```

When I subtract `$p` from `$m` I am getting back `$m` which is 169172. Can someone please point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You are not subtracting **$p from $m** ! What you are doing is:

```
$m = 100000; //number
$p = -169172;  //number
$su = substr($p,1); //now $su is 169172
echo $su - $p; // 169172 -(-169172)
//which is 338344
```

What you should do is(if i understand correctly)

```
$m = 100000; //number
$p = -169172;  //number
$su = substr($p,1); //now $su is 169172
echo $su - $m; // 169172 - 100000
//which is 69172
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last line of code:

```
echo $su - $p;
```

Is not doing what you intend to do (p - m)

It should read:

```
echo $su - $m;
```

If this still outputs 0, I would suggest that your SQL statement for $m is returning 0.